# Apt-Get Hangs on Raspberry Pi in unpacking libboost1.55

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, apt

I've been attempting to install libboost1.55-dev on my Raspberry Pi, but it continually hangs on Unpacking.

After many attempts I've resorted to trying apt-get install -f (considering the package is now broken on the Pi) 
Here is the readout:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Correcting dependencies... Done
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer      required:
   libfreerdp-cache1.1 libfreerdp-client1.1 libfreerdp-codec1.1
   libfreerdp-common1.1.0 libfreerdp-core1.1 libfreerdp-crypto1.1
   libfreerdp-gdi1.1 libfreerdp-locale1.1 libfreerdp-primitives1.1
   libfreerdp-rail1.1 libfreerdp-utils1.1 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1      libvncclient0
   libwinpr-crt0.1 libwinpr-crypto0.1 libwinpr-dsparse0.1
   libwinpr-environment0.1 libwinpr-file0.1 libwinpr-handle0.1 libwinpr-heap0.1
  libwinpr-input0.1 libwinpr-interlocked0.1 libwinpr-library0.1
  libwinpr-path0.1 libwinpr-pool0.1 libwinpr-registry0.1 libwinpr-rpc0.1
   libwinpr-sspi0.1 libwinpr-synch0.1 libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 libwinpr-thread0.1
  libwinpr-utils0.1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0
   vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
 Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
 The following extra packages will be installed:
   icu-devtools libboost-atomic1.55-dev libboost-chrono1.55-dev
   libboost-chrono1.55.0 libboost-context1.55-dev libboost-context1.55.0
   libboost-coroutine1.55-dev libboost-date-time1.55-dev
  libboost-exception1.55-dev libboost-filesystem1.55-dev
   libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.55.0
   libboost-graph1.55-dev libboost-graph1.55.0 libboost-iostreams1.55-dev
   libboost-locale1.55-dev libboost-locale1.55.0 libboost-log1.55-dev
   libboost-log1.55.0 libboost-math1.55-dev libboost-math1.55.0
  libboost-mpi-python1.55-dev libboost-mpi-python1.55.0 libboost-mpi1.55-dev
  libboost-mpi1.55.0 libboost-program-options1.55-dev libboost-python1.55-dev
  libboost-random1.55-dev libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-regex1.55-dev
  libboost-serialization1.55-dev libboost-serialization1.55.0
  libboost-signals1.55-dev libboost-signals1.55.0 libboost-system1.55-dev
   libboost-test1.55-dev libboost-test1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55-dev
  libboost-timer1.55-dev libboost-timer1.55.0 libboost-wave1.55-dev
  libboost-wave1.55.0 libboost1.55-dev libboost1.55-tools-dev libcr0
  libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1
  libicu-dev libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi1.6 libsctp1 lksctp-tools
  mpi-default-bin mpi-default-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 openmpi-bin
   openmpi-common
 Suggested packages:
  graphviz libboost1.55-doc gccxml libmpfrc++-dev libntl-dev xsltproc doxygen
  docbook-xml docbook-xsl default-jdk fop blcr-dkms libhwloc-contrib-plugins
   icu-doc opencl-icd gfortran openmpi-checkpoint
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icu-devtools libboost-atomic1.55-dev libboost-chrono1.55-dev
  libboost-chrono1.55.0 libboost-context1.55-dev libboost-context1.55.0
  libboost-coroutine1.55-dev libboost-date-time1.55-dev
  libboost-exception1.55-dev libboost-filesystem1.55-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.55.0
  libboost-graph1.55-dev libboost-graph1.55.0 libboost-iostreams1.55-dev
  libboost-locale1.55-dev libboost-locale1.55.0 libboost-log1.55-dev
  libboost-log1.55.0 libboost-math1.55-dev libboost-math1.55.0
  libboost-mpi-python1.55-dev libboost-mpi-python1.55.0 libboost-mpi1.55-dev
  libboost-mpi1.55.0 libboost-program-options1.55-dev libboost-python1.55-dev
  libboost-random1.55-dev libboost-random1.55.0 libboost-regex1.55-dev
  libboost-serialization1.55-dev libboost-serialization1.55.0
  libboost-signals1.55-dev libboost-signals1.55.0 libboost-system1.55-dev
  libboost-test1.55-dev libboost-test1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55-dev
  libboost-timer1.55-dev libboost-timer1.55.0 libboost-wave1.55-dev
   libboost-wave1.55.0 libboost1.55-tools-dev libcr0 libhwloc-dev
  libhwloc-plugins libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libicu-dev
  libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi1.6 libsctp1 lksctp-tools mpi-default-bin
  mpi-default-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 openmpi-bin openmpi-common
 The following packages will be upgraded:
  libboost1.55-dev
 1 upgraded, 59 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
 2 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B/22.1 MB of archives.
 After this operation, 188 MB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
 Extracting templates from packages: 100%
(Reading database ... 133407 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libboost1.55-dev_1.55.0+dfsg-3_armhf.deb ...
     Unpacking libboost1.55-dev:armhf (1.55.0+dfsg-3) over (1.55.0+dfsg-3) ...
```

What do I do!

EDIT: output of dpkg --configure -a

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-graph-     parallel1.55-dev:
  libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
   Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-exception1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-exception1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-exception1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-system1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-system1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-system1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-coroutine1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-coroutine1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-coroutine1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-     serialization1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-serialization1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-serialization1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-test1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-test1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
   Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-test1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost1.55-all-     dev:
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-coroutine1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-coroutine1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-exception1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-exception1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev is not configured yet.
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-iostreams1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-iostreams1.55-dev is not installed.
 libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-locale1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-locale1.55-dev is not installed.
  libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-log1.55-dev; however:
  Package libboost-log1.55-dev is not installed.
  libboost1.55-all-dev depends on libboost-math1.55-dev; however:
  Package l
 dpkg: error processing package libboost1.55-all-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-     chrono1.55-dev:armhf:
  libboost-chrono1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-chrono1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-filesystem1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-filesystem1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.
  libboost-filesystem1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost-system1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost-system1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-filesystem1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-date-time1.55-dev:armhf:
 libboost-date-time1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.
  libboost-date-time1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost-serialization1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost-serialization1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-date-time1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-atomic1.55-dev:armhf:
  libboost-atomic1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-atomic1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-graph1.55-     dev:armhf:
 libboost-graph1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.
 libboost-graph1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost-serialization1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost-serialization1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.
 libboost-graph1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost-test1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost-test1.55-dev:armhf is not configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-graph1.55-dev:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-     context1.55-dev:armhf:
  libboost-context1.55-dev:armhf depends on libboost1.55-dev (= 1.55.0+dfsg-3); however:
  Package libboost1.55-dev:armhf is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package libboost-context1.55-dev:armhf (--     configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 libboost-graph-parallel1.55-dev
 libboost-exception1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-system1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-coroutine1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-serialization1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-test1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost1.55-all-dev
 libboost-chrono1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-filesystem1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-date-time1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-atomic1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-graph1.55-dev:armhf
 libboost-context1.55-dev:armhf
```

Comment: While related to installing boost this really isn't a programming question; it's plain debian use on slow hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it hangs? It might take a little while. On my Pi it took 20-30 minutes.

If it takes even longer you can try to download it again via:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

I would also suggest to clean unused packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain. Basically, if I let it sit long enough it boots the SSH connection. Then I waited even longer (hours and hours) and checked to see if it was still running and it was. (ps aux | grep apt-get) Also several times the PI has stopped responding altogether in this scenario.

Comment: Got commanded to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` And that spat out quite a bit. Added above.

Comment: This seems to be happening to me too, and htop reports that `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.55-dev_1.55.0+dfsg-3_armhf.deb` is using about 0.5 CPU%. There are three of these processes; two children of the third. I'll let it run overnight and then check again, but I'm pretty sure I already let it go untimed for about an hour earlier today, before reformatting and trying again.

Comment: ... Well, it looks like it completed after about an hour and 15 minutes, which is pretty painful. My provisioning process didn't used to be that long ... I guess I need to track down which of my requested packages is recommending it, and maybe suppress that.